# Receiving 403 error once in a while, when trying to send a request from http client in Go

Tags: go, http, https, authorization

```
func PrepareRequest(ctx context.Context, method, endpoint, apiResource, path string, data interface{}, parameter string) (*http.Request, error) {
    url := https + ip + "/" + apiResource + "/" + path + "/" + endpoint + parameter
    logger.With(log.Fields{"url": url}).Debug(ctx, "preparing-request")
    var jsonData []byte
    if data != nil {
        jsonData, _ = json.Marshal(data)
    }
    req, err := http.NewRequest(method, url, bytes.NewBuffer(jsonData))
    if err != nil {
        logger.With(log.Fields{"error": err, "endpoint": endpoint, "param": parameter, "data": data}).Error(ctx, "could-not-create-new-http-request")
        return nil, err
    }
    req.Close = true
    req.Header.Add("Cookie", "session=em+protection-user=adm&em+protection-pw=123123123")
    req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "yang-data+json")
    logger.With(log.Fields{"data": string(jsonData), "url": url}).Info(ctx, "request-is-ready")
    return req, nil
}
```

This is the function that I create a request, after preparing this request I'm sending it as follows to the server:

```
resp, err := HttpCli.Do(&req)
```

However, the 403 error 'you don’t have permission to access this resource'. I'm 100% sure that cookie's value is true. If I make 20 request I received this 403 error only one time.

And this is how I Create my httpClient

```
HttpCli = &http.Client{}
ignoreCert := http.Transport{TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true}}
HttpCli.Transport = &ignoreCert
```

What could be the possible problem here? Is it client problem which is this code? Or might be server related?

I changed content-type, commented out req.Close, etc.

Comment: Everything seems ok. And 19 requests out of 20 resolving successfully suggests that the problem is not on the client side

Comment: you can capture data with wireshark and compare with a good request. You can also test with curl. Perhaps there is a problem when the header.